# java chronicle messages are not removed after reading

Tags: java, messaging, chronicle

I am trying to use Java Chronicle 1.9.2 to write/read messages. I know newer versions are available but have few questions before i invest more time in it.

I need to have the message removed once i read the Excerpt from the Chronicle.
So if my reader starts again it doesn't go back to the beginning.
Also message is of no use to me once i read it so want to remove it.

Is there an option to do it? i am trying following code and every time i start reader, i get all the messages again.
Also Is there an option to put a Time to Live on message so it is automatically removed after certain time period.

WRITER -

```
        String tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        String basePrefix = tempPath  + "chronicle";
        System.out.println("base prefix: " + basePrefix);
        Chronicle chr = new IndexedChronicle(basePrefix);
        final Excerpt excerpt = chr.createExcerpt();
        excerpt.startExcerpt(this.getmsgtext().length() + 4);
        excerpt.writeBytes(this.getmsgtext());
        excerpt.finish();
        chr.close();
```

READER -

```
        String tempPath = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        String basePrefix = tempPath +  "chronicle";
        System.out.println("base prefix: " + basePrefix);
        Chronicle chr = new IndexedChronicle(basePrefix);
        final Excerpt excerpt = chr.createExcerpt();

        while (excerpt.nextIndex()) {
                System.out.println("Read string from chronicle: " + excerpt.readByteString());
        }
        chr.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to have the message removed once i read the Excerpt from the Chronicle.

The only way to remove them is with file rolling.  You can do this yourself with IndexedChronicle or using VanillaChronicle or the current SingleChronicleQueue

> So if my reader starts again it doesn't go back to the beginning. Also message is of no use to me once i read it so want to remove it.

The standard practice is to write your results, including the source id, to a Chronicle. This way you always know which messages have been processed successfully. e.g. you could have message read but not processed if a crash occurs.

> i am trying following code and every time i start reader, i get all the messages again.

That is what it is designed to do by default. How you keep track of which messages were processed correctly is up to you. (Though we recommend recording this in another queue and reading the last message to find that index)

> Is there an option to put a Time to Live on message so it is automatically removed after certain time period.

You can add a timestamp to each message and ignore old messages.

Chronicle Queue v4.1.0 is the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response while i was thinking about editing! I am thinking of resetting the file every 5 min or so whether messages are read or not since its the last few minutes situation that i want to analyze.Is there an option to reset the pointer in Chronicle (above code) or i delete , recreate it etc.<BR>If i am i able to reset the index will all readers get latest position with excerpt.netIndex()?

Comment: @chappalprasad The only sure way to reset it to start a new file. You can use clear() for testing purposes.  Queue is generally used when you need to persist messages over a longer period of time to minimise logging, and support replying messages from production to solve bugs and performance issues.

Comment: How do i go to records based on lets say last 5 minutes in above READER code? I see index(long vIndex) method but do i calculate the vIndex to pass based on some fixed record size etc...

Comment: @chappalprasad the index is the number of the message written.  You can get either the index of the message you just wrote and remember it or you can start at the end and go backwards by index-- (or start at the start and go forwards) In the latest version indexes within a cycle are predictable, in previous versions you could get gaps for implementation reasons.

Comment: Getting exception - "Len cannot be " + len + " > 255"    Any specific reason for placing this limit on message size? I probably need 15-16kb data in a single message. Thanks

Comment: @chappalprasad I don't remember, it's a really old version. The newest version has a limit of 1 GB.

Comment: switched to 4.1.0 but looks like it doesn't work with java 1.7 which is what i need to test it in. Thanks for your prompt responses Peter.

Comment: i was trying 3.6.0/4.1.0 versions. But i dont see ExcerptTrailer method to read a String. (readByteString) or similar. Also same classes in old-chronicle but looks like some needed in new version also. is this still in early development.......

Comment: @chappalprasad Currently v4.1.0 supports either Objects which are marshalled or Bytes. I will add a helper method to support a String.

Comment: @chappalprasad in v4.1.0 you need ExcerptAppender.writeText() and ExcerptTailer.readText() note wrieText will write a CharSequence such as a StringBuilder.